# Reading Most Recent Record Multiple Times

Tags: c#, sql

```
Tables: Wo_History /*examples would be in here*/, WO
```

I am trying to access the most recent record for multiple records for Workorders in SQL Server Express.  An example of this would be...

```
ID   Date        Action        Status
1    2016-1-11   'Reopen'      'Not Completed'
1    2016-1-10   'Completed'   'Completed'
1    2016-1-9    'Opened'      'Not Completed'

2    2016-1-20   'Completed'   'Completed'
2    2016-1-19   'Saved'       'Not Completed'
2    2016-1-18   'Opened'      'Not Completed'
```

If it was not for the fact that the Workorder could be reopened then I could just search for 'Completed'.  In this case my final results would be...

```
ID   Date        Action        Status
1    2016-1-11   'Reopen'      'Not Completed'

2    2016-1-20   'Completed'   'Completed'
```

So I would know that Workorder 1 is not completed and Workorder 2 is completed.  I can not figure out how to get these results using only one query and not searching for just one Workorder at a time.  Thanks.

**EDIT 1**
I looked at the question that answers this one... [Where clause on joined table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35652752/where-clause-on-joined-table).  I am a little confused on getting it to work in my case.  I have tried several things and an example using my table would be wonderful.  I attempted both `SELECT DISTINCT` (from Gordon Linoff) and `INNER JOIN` (from Bux) and did not have much success.  Thanks.

**EDIT 2**
I found an answer that works here... [How to get unique set of rows from SQL where uniqueness is defined by 2 columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225690/how-to-get-unique-set-of-rows-from-sql-where-uniqueness-is-defined-by-2-columns) ...from the user Andomar

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY WO_Num ORDER BY DateTime DESC) AS rn, * FROM WO_History)sub WHERE rn = 1 AND Status = ?
```

And I added the 'AND Status = ?' and the '?' is either Completed or Not Completed depending on which one I want to find.

**EDIT 3**

I do not know if anyone is going to see this but I would like to thank [Tom H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5696608/tom-h) for doing a useless duplicate and not helping what so ever.  Thanks again Tom :-)

Comment: I think you should determine the max date for each ID, and that would be the most recent record for the ID.